# MySQL COUNT With group_concat

Tags: mysql, count, group-concat

I have to query multiple tables in a database to create a list of items, then in order to display the list in pages I have to get the total number of rows using COUNT.

My SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT
    j.jid,
    j.reference,
    group_concat(COALESCE(p.canview, u.canview)) AS canview
FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN usergroups u ON (u.gid IN (1,2,3))
LEFT JOIN permissions p ON (p.jid = j.jid) AND (p.gid = u.gid)
GROUP BY j.jid
HAVING FIND_IN_SET('1', canview) > 0
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Essentially all I want to know is if it's possible, by altering the above query, that I can get the total number of rows returned before the `LIMIT`. I've tried added a `COUNT(j,jid)` but that returns 3 (I think this is the number of rows concatenated with the `group_concat`) instead of the desired 9 rows currently in the `jobs` database that have *canview* set to 1.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the query.

Then run a second query to count the rows:

```
select found_rows()
```

It is documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

EDIT:

To get the total without rows, use the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` keyword it the `select`:

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS . . .
```

Then `found_rows()` will return the total without the `limit`.

Comment: I tried this, and it worked without a `LIMIT` but I was looking for the total number of rows that this query would return if I didn't use `LIMIT`.

Comment: I tried the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` keyword, but after a bit of Googling it turns out that it is a lot slower than a simple `COUNT(*)`, is there any way to get the same result using my query and a `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: @user3260082 . . . You would have to run the query twice.  One with the `count(*)` to get the count and the other to get the rows themselves.

Comment: OK so I managed to get it working using a subquery select and counting the results. Thanks for your help.